# give the lat and lng,get the city of radius x mile

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, radius, geonames, city

when use give a lat and lng ,i should give the city and State of US.
 try to use google map place api, but it didn't has the [place type](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)

search in google, get some answers :

1.create the database of city data,and use the sql to calculate the distance.but I didn't get any accurate data,and some data are not free.

2.use the third database [geoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html),get the data, but I worry the website limit the count of request.
So did you have any answer ,help

Comment: You probably want to use the geocoder. See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/5S3ce/ and watch the console for the results. If you have issues getting the information you want, open a new question with code that shows what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lat, and lng, you better got for calling Geocoder.geocode.
Once you get OK in resonse, you can check address_componenets with type "administrative_area_level_n"

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                        for (var b = 0; b < results[0].address_components[i].types.length; b++) {
                            if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_2") {
                                var city = results[0].address_components[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please post complete and working code and explain what it does.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, looks self explanatory to me, but added as per your request (for the sake of completeness)

Comment: It might be for you and others too. But many people here are beginner programmers and therefore posting complete code is always better. Thanks for updating your code.